# Check if any cell in specified range meets 2 conditions

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting, logical-operators

I'm putting together a macro that sends alert e-mails if two conditions are met.

The e-mails are being sent, but indiscriminately and not just when the conditions I want to set are being met.
The conditions: send an e-mail **if any cell inside the range (I1:I9999) has white as background colour AND contains the text "QC".**
This is what I have tried:

```
 var QCJobRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("WIP").getRange("I1:I9999"); 
  var Location = QCJobRange.getValue();

  // Check for white cells with value=QC in Location column

  if (Location = "QC") and (Background = "#ffffff");

// Fetch the email address
var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("WIP").getRange("C2");
var emailAddress = emailRange.getValues();

// Send Alert Email.
var message = 'bla';
var subject = 'bla';
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
```

I'm working directly in the script editor that you can open from Google sheets.
It seems that some operators are not being picked up, f. e. "and" is not even highlighted and I get the following error message: *"and" is not defined*.

I've been combing the forums for a simple solution but am kind of stuck on the problem with "and".
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

[Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) is based on [Javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/)

- The syntax for "and" is `&&`
- The syntax for an `if` statement is `if(condition1&&condition2){...do something...};`
- The method [`getValue()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue) is applicable to a single value (from a single cell), while [`getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) is to be used for value ranges, which represent 2-dimentsional arrays
- If you want to compare two values, use the operator `==`

Here is a sample to modify your code in roder to send a message if the background of cell "I1" is white and its value "QC":

```
function myFunction() {
  //if you do not have 999 rows full of data, please reduce your range - otherwise your code will be slow
   var QCJobRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("WIP").getRange("I1:I9999"); 
   var Locations = QCJobRange.getValues();
   var firstLocation=Locations[0][0];
  // Check for white cells with value=QC in Location column
  if (firstLocation == "QC"&& QCJobRange.getBackgrounds()[0][0]== "#ffffff"){
    // Fetch the email address
    var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("WIP").getRange("C2");
    var emailAddress = emailRange.getValue();
    // Send Alert Email.
    var message = 'bla';
    var subject = 'bla';
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
```

Please consult the Apps Script tutorial for more samples and information: